# How do I save a custom fields by Anspress

Tags: php, wordpress

I’m not saving this correctly. 
How do I save a custom fields?

▼Cretae new custom field:

```
function custom_form_fields( $form ) {
$form['fields']['check'] = array(
  'type' => 'checkbox',
  'options' => array(
    'check-1' => 'check1',
    'check-2' => 'check2'
  ),
);
return $form;
}
add_filter( 'ap_question_form_fields', 'my_custom_question_field' );
```

▼Save field:

```
function question_mysave( $post_id, $post ) {
global $validate;
  if ( empty( $validate ) ) {
  return;
  }
  $fields = $validate->get_sanitized_fields();
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'check', $fields['check'] );
}    
add_action( 'ap_processed_new_question', array( $this, 'question_mysave' ), 0, 2 );
add_action( 'ap_processed_update_question', array( $this, 'question_mysave' ), 0, 2 );
```

Don’t save the custom field. ¿why?

sample：https://anspress.io/resources/faq/anspress-form-and-validation-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove

```
global $validate;
if ( empty( $validate ) ) {
  return;
}
```

And use this for getting values of a form:

```
$form = anspress()->get_form( 'question_form' );
// Get all sanitized values.
$values = $form->get_values();
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'check', $fields['check']['value'] );
```

Comment: I could not remove it…

Comment: There is one other thing...
What I want is a Mediauploader than a Checkbox.
What I really want to ask is the following contents→
https://teratail.com/questions/140563

Comment: I have updated code to get sanitized value from a from.

Comment: I could not do it because it was difficult.Thank you very much.